# Inconsistent InsertDE /Lookup AmpScript results during Email send (locking?)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, locking

I'm developing a global Marketing Cloud log which logs the assetID each send job utilizes, but having inconsistent results with being able to write and then retrieve a value within the same send.

The assetID is retrieved via an SSJS API call which looks it up based on the current content name. This ID value and associated JobID is written to a data extension.

Since the API request adds unnecessary latency and calls once I already have the data after the first time it runs, I have this code to look it up the first written value:

Lookup("Email_Send_Info_Directory","email_ID","jobID",@jobid)

This worked on the first real send I used it on, 3000 emails were sent and the API call only fired once, only one DE row was written on the very first send of the job.

Running the exact same code on a smaller audience of 4 users, it fired the API 4 times and wrote 4 rows to the logging DE - because apparently the Lookup call didn't retrieve the value written during the first email of the send job.

What's the deal with Marketing Cloud being inconsistent with being able to write, then retrieve a DE row within the same send job? I've heard inconsistent reports on record locking in MC and want to know more.

Comment: You may be experiencing multiple issues with this, first I can think of is cacheing, lookup caches on small DE. If you are geting the value within the email why aren't you just leveraging it downstream? why are you doing. a 2nd lookup? SSJS can set a var to an ampscript var

Comment: I do leverage it downstream within the same code block. However when the "next" time that code is run (for the next email being sent to in the job) the Lookup() call can't seem to return the value that was just written beforehand. Perhaps it runs in parallel?

Comment: I would say you lookup is being cached then